# Prevent Binding before form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have this form, which has this input. I want to prevent the data binding before the submit button is clicked. This is my code:

```
<form data-bind="submit: $root.selectPage.bind($root,$root.rootData.Page() )">


            <input data-bind="value : $root.rootData.Page">
               <button type="submit"> Go to a stupid page </button>


</form>
```

Comment: You mean that you don't want the value entered in the `<input>` to update  `rootData.Page` until form is submitted?

Comment: Yes, it should only update after the submit button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using virtual elements. 
Look at the end of: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html 
Set a flag on summit button pressed.

```
<ul>
    <li>This item always appears</li>
    <!-- ko if: someExpressionGoesHere -->
        <li>I want to make this item present/absent dynamically</li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

Comment: That will not help. I want the input to be visible all the time. All i want its that the input value should only be updated after the submit button is clicked.

Comment: What about setting the value to an observable and update it when the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you bind to a temporary observable (say `rootData.TempPage`) and then copy that value to `rootData.Page` on your submit handler.

Comment: I do not want to add an extra property to my model.